# When and where is `Field.blank` checked by DRF?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    emails = ArrayField(models.EmailField(), default=list)
```

And let's say I have the following Serializer of the model:

```py
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['emails']
```

The `email` field is not *blank-able*, i.e: It's required to set a value for it when submitting a Form of the model, or when making changes to its Admin page.

My understanding is that DRF relies as well on [Django's internal machinery](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L767) to validate whether `emails` is missing on the Serializer data or not. But the thing is that I can't find where (and when) this happens.

I've found that DRF is not calling the Model's `clean()` method anymore ([link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7159#issuecomment-578246256)). But what baffles me is that changing the `blank` value on the field seems to have a direct impact on the Serializer. I have switched to `blank=True`, and then the Serializer would allow it to be saved without that field... Then I switched back to `blank=False`, and the Serializer would fail if `emails` is not present.

So do you have any idea of when and where DRF checks for a field's `blank` value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it simply doesn't. Those are only used across forms and the django admin interface.

I always specify those things on the serializer level, by setting the appropiate arguments for my fields ([doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/)), in this case it would be `allow_blank`.

I am building REST APIs with django, and the only case where the `blank` property on the model field catches me, is when fiddling around on the admin page.

However, there appears to be a package that could be of interest to you:
[django-seriously](https://github.com/tfranzel/django-seriously).

I haven't used it, but it [appears](https://github.com/tfranzel/django-seriously/blob/master/django_seriously/utils/models.py) to call `full_clean()` on every `save()`.
Of course, this has the disadvantage that you will probably loose DRFs nice error messages.

Comment: What baffles me is that changing the `blank` value on the model seems to have a direct impact on the Serializer. I have switched to `blank=True`, and then the Serializer would allow it to be saved without that field... Then I switched back to `blank=False`, and the Serializer would fail if `emails` is not present.

Comment: Maybe, if the field is not present, it is set to `None` by the serializer. And `None` != `""` but thats only a quick guess. But I remember that I struggled with this a few times.

Comment: Yes, maybe... For now I will accept your answer until I find (if it exists) the exact place where this happens. Thanks.